# keep pagination state on fnDraw()

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using `jquery` datatables in my application. I have a problem with my `pagination`, it is resetting when I use   `this.table.dataTable().fnDraw()`.

For every 5 seconds my datatable calls `fnDraw()` while updating the table.  When `this.table.dataTable().fnDraw()` is called first page is displayed, even if the user is on page 2 or other.

Is there an way to keep the pagination state even after `this.table.dataTable().fnDraw()`.

Answer (score 19):

On http://datatables.net/ref the explanation for `fnDraw` says:

```
Parameter:  fnDraw
Type:       function
Inputs:     {bool} [default=true]: Re-filter and resort 
            (if enabled) the table before the draw.
```

So, just tried `this.table.dataTable().fnDraw(false)` and it worked. Stayed on the same page and also sorting stayed the same.

Comment: I tried your solution and able to get the page on which i was before fnDraw, but there is an issue few for the data are not displayed (i.e few rows are missing from the the table).

Comment: How are you retrieving the contents for the table? All at page load or do you fetch them by serverside-processing?

Comment: Well, cant help much without an example of your code. You could try debugging the code with firebug. Just use full DataTable.js (not min) and set some breakpoint in the function.

Comment: Awesome!! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mohd Abdul Mujib i am happy that i could help you.

Comment: I have tried this and it's not working.Its taking me to the first page

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this plugin which does what you want: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnStandingRedraw

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem - `fnDraw(false)` (in the other answer) is problematic, because you lose filter state.