# How to filter a Datatable with custom search inputs and dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using a Datatable to populate a table in my app, and the search filters aren't working.

**Filter code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select.healthPlanSelect').change(function () {
                var input = document.getElementById('HealthPlans');
                console.log(input);
                var filter = input.value;
                console.log(filter);
                var table = document.getElementById('userAccountDetails');
                var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                    var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
                    if (td) {
                        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Table Code** - the table is meant to show on click of the 'Search' button.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#userAccountDetails').DataTable({
            });
            $('#userAccountDetails_wrapper').hide();
            $('#searchUser').click(function () {
                $('#userAccountDetails_wrapper').show();
                table.search($(this).val()).draw();
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you want .on('click') - what you have here invokes click.

Comment: @Nikki9696 this is now doing some weird things to my table - for example, I am only seeing three entries on the first page, and then more (10) unfiltered entries as I page through the table. Any advice for applying the filter to the entire set of data?

Comment: sorry, deleted a couple comments because I can't read apparently

Comment: okay maybe this is more helpful: a mention here about using fnDraw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998062/datatables-js-pagination-and-search-not-working

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594466/keep-pagination-state-on-fndraw/10597401